# Is this 2008 Sprinter 3500 DPF clogged?

Tags: diesel-particulate-filter, sprinter

[image]We recently got a 2008 Sprinter 3500 which proves to lose power/weak in power. After looking through the repair history, the last recommendation from the dealer is to change DPF after replacing parts.

I tried to clean the DPF onsite using molley but the issue remained and wife mentioned the engine stopped two times recently.

So I just removed the DPF but can't tell if it is bad or not. I don't see the filter covered completely by soot but it does seem dirty.

I took pictures of the up and down stream filters and hope someone will give me some feedback.

By the way, if I shine a flashlight from one end, should I see at least a weak light from the other side or the two filters are arranged in the way I will not see any light even they are not clogged?

The photo of the clean filter is the downstream one while the one looks dirty is the up stream one.

Thanks in advance.[image]

Comment: MIleage of engine? Can you insert a temporary bypass pipe in place of the dpf to see if  engine performance improves? Any record of injector maintenance?

Comment: @FDryer Around 300,000KM. The previous service comments did say by removing the DPF, the engine seemed back with power and that's why they recommend replace DPF. The strange thing is I don't see the normal black soot except at the edge. I did tried using moly to clean it a few month ago. As for the injector, I believe that is also changed a year or two ago.

Comment: If this engine appears to have power with dpf removed, this may suggest lost compression or other issues not easily diagnosed. Diesel compression may the heart of diesel engines with mechanical or electronic fuel injection adding to complexity. Extensive diagnostic procedures are available online to help diyers.